# Node js + PhantomJs: send data to page.evaluate

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

How can I send variable from server to page.evaluate ?

```
var test = 'Lorem Ipsum';

phantom = require('phantom')
    phantom.create(function(ph){
        ph.createPage(function(page) {
            page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
            page.evaluate(function(){
               $('body').html(test);
            });
            page.render('google.pdf', function(){

             console.log('Page Rendered');
             ph.exit();
           });
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Edit1**

Now it look like

```
var message = function(){
    return {message: 'Hello Word'};
};

phantom = require('phantom')
    phantom.create(function(ph){
        ph.createPage(function(page) {
            page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
            page.evaluate(function(content){
               $('body').html(content);
            }, message);
            page.render('google.pdf', function(){

             console.log('Page Rendered');
             ph.exit();
           });
       });
    });
});
```

Now I haven't any error, but I don't know how can I handle this object to use it in page.evaluate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try with**

```
page.evaluate(function (...) {...}, function (err, data){...}, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

example:

```
var message = 'hello world';
page.evaluate(function(content){
    $('body').html(content);
    return 'any data'
}, function (err, anydata) {}, message);
```

Adding jquery to page

```
page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', function(err) {
    //jQuery Loaded.
    //Wait for a bit if site have AJAX
    setTimeout(function() {
        return page.evaluate(function() {
            // USE JQUERY HERE
            //
            //

            return
        }, function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            ph.exit();
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

**see readme at:**
https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom

Comment: now I have error in console:

    phantom stdout: TypeError: 'hello world' is not a function (evaluating 'cb(page.evaluate.apply(page, [fn].concat(args)))')

Comment: I try to do someting like this
`var message = function(){
    return {message : 'hello world'};
 };` but now I don't know how can I handle this object to use it in page.evaluate

Comment: ah, sorry, you are using phantom for node (a bridge to phantomjs). evaluate will return result via callback.

Comment: google do not use jquery, so you do not have $ inside phantom page. you can try another page or use page.includeJs('http://path to a jquery cdn')